# Can HTTP response customized in IBM ODM

Tags: rule-engine, ibm-odm

can http status code and message be customized in IBM ODM ?

i see we can do exception handling in ODM, but the message goes to error logs and i dont see a way to customize http response and message (link attached blow)
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.10.x/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/shared_optimizing/tsk_excpt_custom.html

My Analysis :

please correct me if i'm wrong

1) Technical Exceptions are automatically handled with 400 and 500 status codes, i don't see any way to customize it

ex:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "An error occurred during the execution of the ruleset. Make sure that the request is valid, and review the ruleset and execution object model if applicable.",

}

{
    "code": 404,
    "message": "An error occurred during the initialization of the execution, make sure that the ruleset matches the execution requirements.",
    "details": "Cannot get the information about the ruleset /project/1.0/service/1.1. Make sure that you have deployed the ruleset and that the enable property is set correctly.\n",
    "errorCode": "GBRXH0501E"
}
```

2) Business Exception can only be handled with Http response 200, creating additional exception object and passing error code and message in it

Ex:

```
{
    "status": null,
    "Exception": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": state 'NJ' does not contain any business logic,
                 }

}
```